# redirect to intended page with guard in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have two guards in my project ( its searching flight project that customers and offices can search for flights )

1 - customer
2 - office

when office/customer searchs for flight I will show it many flights and when it selects one of them I will redirect office/customer to login page

I want to redirected customer/office to after success login but with diffrente route related to guard

for example
customer : (myDomain.com/customer/flight-list)
office : (myDomain.com/flight-list)

I use intended method for this but it always redirects to (myDomain.com/flight-list)

actually office is ok and works currect and redirects to (myDomain.com/flight-list)

but customer does not redirect to (myDomain.com/customer/flight-list)

by the way i've used   `return redirect()->intended('/customer');`
but not work

```
 public function loginStore(StoreLoginRequest $request)
    {
        $inputs = $request->all();

        //check id is email or not
        if (filter_var($inputs['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $type = 1; // 1 => email
            $customer = User::where('email', $inputs['id'])->first();
            if (empty($customer)) {
                return back()->with('swal-error', 'Customer Not Found !!!');
            } else {
                $credentials = ['email' => $inputs['id'], 'password' => $inputs['password']];
                if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($credentials)) {
                    return redirect()->intended();
                }
                return back()->with('swal-error', 'Customer Not Found !!!');
            }
        }
    }
```

**In short, I want append '/customer' to intended method if guard is customer**